# Background animation like Flipboard android application

Tags: android, animation, background, flipboard

I want to implement animation like flipboard welcome screen. How to make automatically scrolling animation in background. Anyone have any idea or example..?

check this [gif image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L5PpaPDwtMUnhtclAydjZWdkE/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be video with shimmer effect on up arrows.

Comment: thanks for help, but its not video. I dont't need shimmer effect on arrow, i need background animation,which auto scroll all topic names.